# Finding the number of combinations of secret santa pairs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am currently attempting to calculate the number of potential unique combinations of unique pairs of a set of Secret Santa participants. This topic was discussed at length last year and nobody knew how to go about working it out - this year I want to be prepared!

What I have so far is that I can derive the number of possible unique pairs by subtracting 1 from the number of participants `n`, which I then multiply by the number of participants `n`, and finally divide by 2:

$\frac{n\times(n-1)}{2}$

Here's an example:

$\frac{6\times(6-1)}{2} = 15$

What I now need to find out is how many potential combinations of those pairs are possible...

...so if there are 4 participants in Secret Santa:

`[A, B, C, D]`

Using my formula above, there would be 6 unique pairs:

`[A,B],[A,C],[A,D],[B,C],[B,D],[C,D]`

I know that the possible unique combinations of those pairs are:

`[[A,B],[C,D]],
[[A,C],[B,D]],
[[A,D],[B,C]]`

But I cannot figure out how to calculate this mathematically. Also, to add a spanner in the works, I would like to be able to calculate this whilst taking couples into consideration. So, if `[A,B]` are not a couple, then no unique pair or combination of pairs should include them. I obviously would just subtract the number of couples from the number of unique pairs, but for combinations I haven't got the foggiest.

Please forgive me if I am going about all this the wrong way, or haven't provided the right information. Also, can any answers given please include a working example? - thanks!

Comment: What are you asking? You are probably unable to find an answer because you can't come up with a description of the problem better than "number of combinations of secret santa pairs". This description is meaningless to the majority of the human race. I am aware of the tedious tradition that you are talking about, but I wouldn't expect it to mean anything to other members of the MSE community.

Comment: @RobArthan Have you not played that game at work ? where you buy gifts for someone & someone (probably different) buys gifts for you, in the week before Christmas. And then you get to find out who your secret Santa is at the Christmas party.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I think you missed Rob's point. I think the key part is that Secret Santa is a tradition that a small percentage of the world population know about, and this limits the percentage of people that understand the question innecesarily.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: please read my comment more carefully. I **am** part of the minority of the human race that is aware of this tedious tradition. I object to the OP assuming this knowledge of an office game as if it were a mathematical definition.

Comment: @RobArthan I am sorry. I guess the OP assumed we knew what "secret Santa" means. The question is even worse than that it actively misleads the uninformed to assume the people must be paired up.

Comment: @OP To alleviate the concerns raised in the comments, you should formally define how Secret Santa works. I would say that you have $n$ people and each person gives a gift to a person besides themselves. Mathematically, this is looking for derangements on a set of $n$ elements, as Donald Splutterwit described in his post.

Comment: It seems to me that the Question asks about counting "how many potential combinations of those pairs are possible" rather than (as may appear at first glance) about counting the distinct possible pairs.  Then the Question is essentially a duplicate of the many previous posts at Math.SE about counting *derangements* as others have noted.  I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to pair the peolpe up, they will all know who they are paired with and that will defeat the "secret" of who their Santa is.

What you need is a permutation of the set of people with no fixed points, these are known as derrangements, in combinatorial parlance. Your example with $4$ people will have $9$ possibilities. See here for more info about derrangements https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement .

To calculate the number of derrangements the recurrence relation is $d_n=(n-1)(d_{n-1}+d_{n-2})$ and the first few values are $1,0,1,2,9,44,265,\cdots $

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have $2n$ persons $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{2n}$.

Notice each permutation of the persons gives us a pairing by pairing up the first two persons, the next two persons and so on.

For example, the permutation $a_1,a_4,a_2,a_3,a_6,a_5$ gives us the pairs $[a_1,a_4],[a_2,a_3],[a_6,a_5]$.

Every possible paring can be obtained in this way in exactly $2^n n!$ ways. (because there are $n!$ ways to order the pairs and $2^n$ ways to order the two persons within the pairs).

The answer is thus $\frac{(2n)!}{n!2^n}$